# How to control system LEDs from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, system

Is there a way to control the system LEDs (power, network, caps lock, num lock, charge, etc) from the terminal?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the default ones on the keyboard (NumLock, CapsLock, ScrollLock) there is `setleds`, for the others you might have luck playing around with `/sys/class/leds/` (at your own risk).

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing around with `/sys/class/leds/` and that seems like the way to go for me :)

Comment: would be glad if you'd like to share some results (-: